# Create a dummy to indicating presence of string fragment in any of multiple variables

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

```
df <- data.frame (address.1.line = c("apartment 5", "25 spring street", "nice house"), address.2.line = c("london", "new york", "apartment 2"), address.3.line = c("", "", "paris"))
```

I'm trying to make a function that returns a new column in a data frame. The column should be a dummy variable attached to the original data frame indicating whether any of 3 address-line variables contain a string (or selection of strings).

E.g., in the example above, I want df to have a new variable called "Apartment_dummy" indicating the presence of the string fragment "apartment" in any of the three address lines---so it will take 1 in rows 1 and 3, and zero in row 0. The function needs to take 2 arguments, therefore: the name of the new dummy variable to be created, and the corresponding string fragment that needs to be detected in the address variables.

I'd tried the following. It will return a dummy, but won't give the new variable the right name. Also, I feel like there must be a way to do it in a single step. Any ideas? Many thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
premises_dummy <- function(varname = NULL, strings = NULL) {
df %<>%    mutate_at(.funs = funs(flagA = str_detect(., strings)), .vars = vars(ends_with(".line"))) %>% 
       mutate(varname = ifelse(rowSums(select(., contains("flagA"))) > 0, 1, 0))
return(df)
}

df <- premises_dummy(varname = 'Apartment_dummy', strings = 'apartment')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R solution :

```
 cols = endsWith(names(df),"line")
 df['Apartment_dummy'] = as.integer(grepl('apartment',do.call(paste,df[cols])))
```

Now we can write a function that even considers the data to be used ie,data bein an argument.

```
premises_dummy=function(varname,strings){
   cols = endsWith(names(df),"line")
   df[varname]= as.integer(grepl(strings,do.call(paste,df[cols])))
   df
 }
 premises_dummy(varname = 'Apartment_dummy', strings = 'apartment')
    address.1.line address.2.line address.3.line Apartment_dummy
1      apartment 5         london                              1
2 25 spring street       new york                              0
3       nice house    apartment 2          paris               1
```

Comment: This gets me super close. But in the application I have other variables in the df too. How can I get it to only search for the presence of string fragments in the 3 address line variables, and not the other variables?

Answer (score 1):

A quick `data.table` solution to it:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
search_string <- "apartment"
dt[like(address.1.line, search_string)| 
   like(address.2.line, search_string)| 
   like(address.3.line, search_string), paste0(search_string,".Dummy") := 1]

dt[is.na(get(paste0(search_string,".Dummy"))), paste0(search_string,".Dummy") := 0]
```

Comment: Very many thanks, but this isn't a function (I need to apply it to make a bunch of new columns based on different strings) and I'd prefer a tidyverse solution for consistency.

Comment: Well, you can just make the column name and the search string dynamic.

Comment: Just updated the answer to be usable with a dynamic search string. Should work for multiple search terms.

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` option using `tidyr::unite` and `stringr::str_detect`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    unite(tmp, remove = F) %>%
    mutate(Apartment_dummy = +str_detect(tmp, "apartment")) %>%
    select(-tmp)
#    address.1.line address.2.line address.3.line Apartment_dummy
#1      apartment 5         london                              1
#2 25 spring street       new york                              0
#3       nice house    apartment 2          paris               1
```